# wget is blocked from downloading .FLV file, while curl isn't

Tags: shell, wget

In my terminal:

```
url='http://58.30.207.171/youku/69764FC8BC2447992487A2488/030002010051001478A6FA0109ACBF22B0F614-2746-1AE5-C9EF-2266A1CC83DB.flv'
curl $url -o test1.flv #can download
wget -c $url -O test2.flv #can not download
```

1.Why `wget` can not download it?
2.How can i make `wget` download it?

Comment: Do you suspect it's something about the file content / type?

Comment: the above url return 403 error if using wget, I guess is blocked like what @Floris said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site may be blocking wget specifically. You can override this by setting the user-agent to an empty string:
I found this at http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Option-Syntax

‘-U agent-string’
‘--user-agent=agent-string’
Identify as agent-string to the http server.
The http protocol allows the clients to identify themselves using a User-Agent header field. This enables distinguishing the www software, usually for statistical purposes or for tracing of protocol violations. Wget normally identifies as ‘Wget/version’, version being the current version number of Wget.

However, some sites have been known to impose the policy of tailoring the output according to the User-Agent-supplied information. While this is not such a bad idea in theory, it has been abused by servers denying information to clients other than (historically) Netscape or, more frequently, Microsoft Internet Explorer. This option allows you to change the User-Agent line issued by Wget. Use of this option is discouraged, unless you really know what you are doing.

Specifying empty user agent with ‘--user-agent=""’ instructs Wget not to send the User-Agent header in http requests.